# How to set up share Intent in android.

Tags: android, android-intent, uri

I want to share multiple images with other application using share action provided by android. The below code does not works as intended.

**Sending Activity:**

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
    //intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Here are some files.");
    intent.setType("image/*");

    ArrayList<Uri> files = new ArrayList<Uri>();
    for (String path : imageArray) {
        File file = new File(path);
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        files.add(uri);
    }
    intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, files);
    shareAction.setShareIntent(intent);
```

**Receiving activity code:**

```
 if (Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE.equals(intent.getAction())
          && intent.hasExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM)) {
          ArrayList<Parcelable> list =
         intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
         for (Parcelable p : list) {
           Uri uri = (Uri) p;
           System.out.println("hello world");
         }
     }
```

**Receiving activity output :**

```
file:///absolute-path-to-file
```

I want output in `content://absolute-path-to-file` format. Because i am getting this format when receiving file intent from other applications.
Other possible way to solve this is also recommended.